# A relation between FC groups and locally finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is proved that if $G$ satisfies maximality on non-nearly normal subgroups, denoted with $Max-nn^{-}$ and $K$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$, then $K^{G}$ satisfies the maximal condition on subgroups. 
Now, the proof says that if $G$ is locally finite satisfying $Max-nn^{-}$, $G$ is an FC-group. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the conjugacy class of $g \in G$ is infinite, and let $M = \langle g \rangle^G$. Then $|M:\langle g \rangle|$ is infinite, and we can find an infinite ascending chain of subgroups $\langle x \rangle < \langle x,x_1 \rangle <\langle x,x_1,x_2 \rangle < \cdots $ of finite subgroups of $M$, none of which are nearly cormal, contradicting the maximality condition.

Comment: Why none of them are nearly normal?

Comment: They all have $M$ as normal closure.